# Apache root-relative links

Tags: apache, relative-path

Using apache 2, I have a simple virtual host container:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
  ServerName developmentServer
  DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>
```

The site is accessible, but I'm having trouble using root relative links within the site. I have an 'images' folder that is located at the root level. When I am within a folder or subfolder, I want to specify an image path that is root relative. (And actually all paths will be root relative regardless of the page depth.)  This currently is not working:

```
<img src="/images/file.jpg">
```

But this will:

```
<img src="../images/file.jpg">
```

I understand the difference, but I do not know what needs to be changed in Apache to allow me start all links with a "/" so they are root-relative. I'm thinking there is a configuration setting, and I shouldn't have to rely on mod_rewrite.  Any suggestions?

Comment: How is it not working - does it say `404 Not Found`?

Comment: My mistake, it will work.  On this development platform, the web root was actually one level deeper than what was specified as the DocumentRoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the image located at `/var/www/images/file.jpg` and are you accessing the page containing this image over HTTP (`http://developmentServer/...`)? Then it must work.